# How to add onClick event to add to cart button

Tags: cart, addtocart, magento-2.1.9, facebook

Magento version 2.1.9

I want to use facebook pixel on my magento site. I want to add onclick event to all "add to cart" buttons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add it to the product view, you can go to

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

and add your **onclick** event to the button element around **line 32**.

It is bad practice to add inline js - hat tip to Ben Crook - (see  [here](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)). An alternative would be to add the following to a js file:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("product-addtocart-button").onclick = function () {
        // Add Facebook Pixel Event
    };
}
```

Comment: Inline JS events is bad practice :(

Comment: @BenCrook Thanks for the reminder, yes it is bad practice for multiple reasons. I will add to the answer to give another option.

Comment: As a further improvement, rather than using `window.onload` you can just add `domReady!` as a dependency in require and your JS file will only load once the DOM has finished rendering.